# libgdx отрисовка под любым углом, нужны идеи

Tags: java, libgdx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос состоит в том, как рисовать широкие полосы от круга 1 до круга 2 в любых координатах(иными словами под углом)

Я рисую вот такую полосу, от круга 1 до круга 2, сейчас я могу рисовать только по прямой

где getX и getY расположение координаты круга 1(на котором число), x2,y2 координаты круга 2

Белые полосы и фиолетовую полосы рисую растягивая квадрат 1х1 пиксель(piece)

```
batchColor.begin();
    batchColor.setColor(colorR,colorG,colorB,colorA);
    batchColor.draw(piece,getX(),getY()-getRadius(),x2-getRadius()-getRadius(),y2);

    batchColor.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    batchColor.draw(piece,getX(),getY()+getRadius(),x2-getRadius()-getRadius(),-6);
    batchColor.draw(piece,getX(),getY()-getRadius(),x2-getRadius()-getRadius(),6);
    batchColor.end();
```

(Полигон по предложению Sergey Krasnikov)
Построение полигона:

```
cord = new float[10];
    cord[0] = getX();
    cord[1] = getY()-getRadius();
    cord[2] = getX();
    cord[3] = getY()+getRadius();
    cord[4] = x2;
    cord[5] = y2+getRadius();
    cord[6] = x2;
    cord[7] = y2-getRadius();
    cord[8] = getX();
    cord[9] = getY()-getRadius();
    TextureRegion temp = new TextureRegion(new Texture("1x1.png"));
    EarClippingTriangulator triangulator = new EarClippingTriangulator();
    ShortArray triangleIndices = triangulator.computeTriangles(cord);

    polyReg = new PolygonRegion(temp,
            cord,triangleIndices.toArray());

    poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
    poly.setOrigin(250, 250);
    polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
```

Отрисовка полигона в рендере:

```
polyBatch.begin();
    polyBatch.setColor(Color.RED);
    poly.draw(polyBatch);
    polyBatch.end();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java это можно сделать с помощью Polygon.

Вот пример:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Test extends Frame {

public Test() {
    super("Java 2D Example01");
    setSize(400, 300);
    setVisible(true);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                              dispose();
                              System.exit(0);
                          }
                      }
    );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Test();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Polygon poligon = new Polygon();
    poligon.addPoint(150, 150);
    poligon.addPoint(185, 120);
    poligon.addPoint(250, 200);
    poligon.addPoint(220, 230);
    poligon.addPoint(150, 150);

    ((Graphics2D) g).fill(poligon);
 }
}
```

Вот пример для libgdx:

```
package com.gamename;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.*;

public class Game implements ApplicationListener {
private PolygonSprite poly;
private PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch;

public void create () {

    PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(createTexture()),
            new float[] {
                    150, 150,
                    185, 120,
                    250, 200,
                    220, 230,
                    150, 150
            });

    poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
    poly.setOrigin(100, 100);
    polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
}

public void render () {
    polyBatch.begin();
    poly.draw(polyBatch);
    polyBatch.end();
}

public void resize (int width, int height) {}
public void pause () {}
public void resume () {}
public void dispose () {}

private Texture createTexture() {
    Pixmap pix = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pix.setColor(0xDEADBEFF);
    pix.fill();

    return new Texture(pix);
}
}
```

Класс для вызова с десктопа:

```
package com.gamename;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;

public class DesktopGame {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    new LwjglApplication(new Game(), "Game", 480, 320, false);
}
}
```

Comment: честно говоря, не могу понять как он рисует) у меня всё в рендере через SpriteBatch

Comment: а среди Sprite и SpriteBatch нет ничего, что можно связать с полигоном :(

Comment: Похоже в libgdx аналогом является PolygonSpriteBatch. 
Полигону указываются вершины, по которым строится многоугольник.
Вот здесь нашел пример: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733442/drawing-filled-polygon-with-libgdx.
Там строится полигон, затем поворачивается.

Comment: Добавил  пример для libgdx.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос на основе вашего примера решение) В полигоне правда требуется сейчас три параметра, а не два, третий это некий ShortArray(но пока что не знаю, зачем он))